# Разбить строку на слова

Tags: java, строки

Мне нужно разбить строку на слова, а после проверить, сходятся ли 1-я и последняя буква слова.

Проблема в том, что слово выходит с цикла после 1 раза, ссылаясь на то что, оно выходит за длину. Помогите, не понимаю, как сделать, чтобы оно прошло.

Пишет, что проблема вот в этой строке:`if(substr1.charAt(indexOfSpace) == substr1.charAt(nextIndexOfSpace-1))`

```
  int indexOfSpace = 0;
  int nextIndexOfSpace = 0;

  StringBuffer sentence = new StringBuffer("thit mom wow sentenc");
  int length = sentence.length();

  int lastIndexOfSpace = sentence.lastIndexOf(" "); 
  nextIndexOfSpace = sentence.indexOf(" ",indexOfSpace);  
  String substr1 = sentence.substring(indexOfSpace,nextIndexOfSpace);

  do
  {
      //checking words algorithm
      if(substr1.charAt(indexOfSpace) == substr1.charAt(nextIndexOfSpace-1))
      {
          System.out.println("WORD IS CORRECT");
          System.out.println(substr1);
      }
      else
      System.out.println("NO");

      indexOfSpace = nextIndexOfSpace;
      nextIndexOfSpace = sentence.indexOf(" ",indexOfSpace);  
  }
  while(indexOfSpace != lastIndexOfSpace);

  if(indexOfSpace == lastIndexOfSpace)
  {
      //the last word check
      if(sentence.charAt(lastIndexOfSpace+1) == sentence.charAt(length-1))
      {
          System.out.println(sentence.charAt(lastIndexOfSpace+1));
          System.out.println(sentence.charAt(length-1));
          System.out.println("last word ");
      }
  }
```

Comment: Пробелы надо пропускать.

Comment: "aaa aaa".split(" ")

Answer (score 1):

Можно упростить код, если через `split` слова получить:

```
String text = "thit mom wow sentenc";

for (String word : text.split(" ")) {
    if (word.charAt(0) == word.charAt(word.length() - 1)) {
        System.out.println("WORD IS CORRECT: " + word);
    } else {
        System.out.println("WORD IS NOT CORRECT: " + word);
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
WORD IS CORRECT: thit
WORD IS CORRECT: mom
WORD IS CORRECT: wow
WORD IS NOT CORRECT: sentenc
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что вы обращаетесь к подстроке `substr1`, а индексы ищите в `sentence`.

```
if(sentence.charAt(indexOfSpace) == sentence.charAt(nextIndexOfSpace-1))
```

Еще одна проблема в

```
nextIndexOfSpace = sentence.indexOf(" ",indexOfSpace);
```

должно быть

```
nextIndexOfSpace = sentence.indexOf(" ",indexOfSpace + 1);
```

Comment: Я уже решил проблему...спасибо